# Парсинг WB python selenium или

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Есть у кого нибудь кусок кода на python, который парсит страницу Wildberres целиком как в  Chrome+F12
Там хитрый вывод html через Js
Не могу даже через силениум весь html залить...

Comment: Покажите ваш код таки

Comment: `chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

requiredHtml = driver.page_source`

Comment: https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/0/search.aspx?xfilters=xsubject%3Bdlvr%3Bbrand%3Bprice%3Bkind%3Bcolor%3Bwbsize%3Bseason%3Bconsists&xparams=preset%3D10043037&xshard=presets%2Fbucket_76&search=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0&xsearch=true

Comment: Код добавляйте в текст вопроса